# Conditional Declaring of Extending Class (Overwriting) Method, Based on the Parent Method's Default Parameters

Tags: php, inheritance, joomla

I am creating a plugin for a CMS that provides a few base classes (let's say one of these classes is called `Base`). This class has a few helper methods that must be overwritten in the extending class. We should note that the base methods have default parameters/values provided. In one version of the LMS these values are provided by reference in the next version just by value.

For example (CMS v1.0):

```
function prepareTable(&$table){...
```

CMS v1.1:

```
function prepareTable($table){...
```

When you extend the `Base` class and overwrite the `prepareTable` method you have to declare it with the same default parameters/values as well, otherwise a STRICT PHP warning is displayed (on by default in PHP 5.4).

My question is, how do I conditionally overwrite the method from the parent class in a working way, knowing the version of the parent CMS?

Here's what I have currently (not working at the moment):

```
class Base{
    function prepareTable(&$table){
    }
}

class Extending extends Base{
    if(CMS_VERSION=='1.0')
      function prepareTable(&$table){
    else
      function prepareTable($table){

       echo $table;
    }
}
```

Obviously, I can not edit the `Base` and its method directly.

EDIT: Here's the exact error message:

```
Strict standards: Declaration of Extending::prepareTable() should be compatible with Base::prepareTable($table) in.
```

Comment: I would keep `function prepareTable(&$table){` (reference) but only change $table if CMS_VERSION is '1.0'. Ie `$temp=$table;` (copy) and before leaving the function `if(CMS_VERSION=='1.0') $table=$temp;`

Comment: Could you ellaborate. The base class` method in version 1.1 of the CMS declares the default parameter as value only `$table`, wherease if I use your solution and leave the extending class` method with a default value as reference, the STRICT PHP warning is displayed.

Comment: Ah! you have 2 different base classes. v1 is prepareTable(&$table) and v1.1 is prepareTable($table). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but not at the same time. v1 had the one with the reference (`&$table`) and v1.1 has the one without the reference.

Comment: The only way I see here is to define conditionally parent prepareTable() method like you do it in the extended class. Otherwise you always will get this error, because declaration is not the same.

Comment: Yes, but my example doesn't work. I just gave it for illustration purposes as to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way I can think of achieving this without duplicating the code inside prepareTable is to create a pseudo function that gets called inside prepareTable and then declare that in the final extended class

```
if(CMS_VERSION=='1.0') {
    class Base2 extends Base{
        function prepareTable(&$table){
            return $this->prepareTable2($table);
        }
        function prepareTable2(&$table){
        }
    }
} else {
    class Base2 extends Base{
        function prepareTable($table){
            return $this->prepareTable2($table);
        }
        function prepareTable2(&$table){
        }
    }
}
class Extending extends Base2{
    function prepareTable2(&$table){
            echo $table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid duplicating the `Base2` class completely, since there are plenty of other methods and properties inside it as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(CMS_VERSION=='1.0') {
    class Extending extends Base{
        function prepareTable(&$table){

        }
    }
} else {
    class Extending extends Base{
        function prepareTable($table){

        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `if/else` check must be done before the class is defined, not inside the class. Essentially, you are building two different versions of the class.

Side Note: If you need to include shared methods, that won't be changed between the two versions of the class, you can define a new class that will extend `Extending`, create the shared methods there and use this new class.

For example (place this after the code above):

```
class ExtendingFull extends Extending{
    // Here you may include your shared methods
    // e.g:
    public function sharedMethod(){
       echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should've accepted @Waygood 's answer since you basically just copied his.

Comment: Always open for feedback. Just switched the accepted answer. Thanks for pointing out the answer that you found more valuable.